# After Effects Script: Import comps from external project

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

here's the situation:

**What I have:** A .js that selects and adds comps from the project to the active comp based on parameters defined by the user in a dialog prompt.

**What I need:** A .js script that does this but calls and adds the comps from an external AE project, so as to keep the working project clean and light weight.

**Questions:** The import object in the AE scripting guide does not seem to cover this. Is it possible to do it with a .js, or this would require C/C++ with the SDK?

Any help or clues will be much appreciated.

Comment: If it's not something you could do with the UI application, it's not something you can do with extendscript.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible -- what you refer to is some kind of dynamic linking to comps. THere is no way. Comps have to be imported into the new project to work.

A tool which does dynamic comps by referencing them is here>
But it also has to paste the comp into the new project.

[BAO Dynamic Comps](https://aescripts.com/bao-dynamic-comp/)